# Python regex to check if a string contains a method call

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am parsing an xml file in python. I fetch the attribute values of xml nodes for processing.

```
<set name="flashScope.emailSuggestion" value="userBean.createEmailSuggestion(flowRequestContext)" />
```

Using ElementTree, I get the attribute of the node

```
node.attrib['value']
```

which gives me

```
userBean.createEmailSuggestion(flowRequestContext)
```

Now how do I check if this string contains paranthesis `()`? (I mean, to know that it is a method call)..Can anyone suggest a regex pattern for this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: `if "(" in string and ")" in string: ...` ? .. maybe check also that ( before ) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in general:

```
^\w+(\.\w+)+\(.*\)$
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you so much:)